# store a file into a ftp server using apache commons doesn't work

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I am trying to store a file into a ftp server using apache commons java library. I am using commons-net-3.0.1.jar. The problem is when ever i try to push the file into server, the call

StoreFile()

returns false always. It doesn't throw any exception. nothing at all,just reply false silently. If i try to push the file manually i.e using normal "ftp" client in linux systems (I meant connecting to ftp server using ftp command and storing the file using put command), then it puts the file into server.

I have no idea of how to debug it even. Can you please let me know how i can get to know the problem and its solution.

I checked the server logs, when ever i am trying to post through java the log says 425 response code failed to establish connection. But when i use manually it shows 226 response.

Comment: Please check that you are using the same username and password for both, or at least make sure that the Java application is using credentials which have the necessary rights. Posting the code you are using will also help.

Comment: `commons-net` is opensource, you can try to debug into their code.

Comment: @npinti :- The credentials are same i checked them, The server logs says "Login successfull"

Comment: @Eli :- i tried to debug using the source code but couldnt get to the problem, i am still trying it, but thought if i keep in this community i will get a pointer to where i can search for

Comment: @Thebestshoot: I would recommend you post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: FTP is not a reliable protocol to upload/download data to/from a server with code. If you need a reliable solution, FTP is not for you. Try ssh instead.

To answer your question: Add a `ProtocolCommandListener` to your `SocketClient` (`FTP` extends this). Then you can at least print the messages in `ProtocolCommandListener()` and `protocolReplyReceived()`

Comment: I tried doing this it works well, but do we have some other tool sort of thing to debug weather the data is going out correctly or not and about the commands, i mean if in productioon environment i get this problem how could i debug this, if i havent had this code? is there  a way of doing

Comment: Add a logging framework to your app. These can be configured with files that you can deploy alongside your app. That way, you can enable/disable logging as you need it. That said: FTP is not a protocol suitable for production use. It's designed for humans, not automatic error recovery so you will spend a couple of hours every week to fix the same problems over and over again.